# What are some open souce VoIP software options for LInux that can record?

Tags: linux, open-source, audio-recording, voip

I am running Ubuntu 21.10 on a Thinkpad X1 Tablet. I pay for a VoIP phone and usually use it via a Grandstream HT502 ATA. But sometimes I would like to use my computer to make the VoIP call. I installed Empathy but [am having a lot of trouble using it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1390595/adding-contacts-and-dialing-out-with-empathy). I am wondering what other open source VoIP software is available and what do people recommend? I hope to record phone interviews with family members about family history so I would like to be able to record.

Answer (score 0):

The [linphone project](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-desktop) meets all these requirements.  Unfortunately the linphone installed from the Ubuntu 21.10 repositories [does not have record working](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linphone-desktop/+bug/1960137), but linphone can be compiled from source.  In addition to the instructions given in the [linphone source repository](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-desktop), I had to run

```
sudo apt install libglew-dev libqt5webview5-dev '^qt.*5-dev$'
```